# Why is my C++ output not showing in VS Code Terminal (GCC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Trying to get the output of my basic C++ program in VS Code but it's not displaying in terminal
[Using the run icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfNOJ.png)

This is what is being in the terminal [Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjTC7.png)

However, if I do this, then the output is shown as usual

[Using Run tab and debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5nh1.png)

[Final-Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzmKC.png)

Please let me know what is happening here, I don't understand why it's happening this way but not the other way

Also, I have this extension installed in case it makes a difference [Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aRNr.png)

Comment: Your file name has a space in between. Whatever extension you're using to run that code is not configured to work with paths having spaces. Refer this: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/248#issuecomment-405000568

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source code file is named "full pyramid".  This is causing the compiler to try to compile it as two separate files, called "full" and "pyramid".  Try naming the file "full_pyramid" instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!
I had one question - Then why was it working when I debugged it through the run tab?

Comment: Glad it worked. If you can accept my answer  by clicking next to it, it's much appreciated. It was working when debugging because the debugger is most likely using a system generated name for the .exe which didn't have spaces in it. Debuggers usually do this.

Comment: It's best to never use a space in the path or file name in `c` or `c++`. The reason is both are compiled using the shell or command line where the space character separates different arguments. To get around this you need to quote the path however as you see not all build tools will handle that automatically and properly for you so its best to avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: @tutiplain Thanks for the explanation, sorry for not accepting the answer I just started using stack and don't know much about it

Comment: @drescherjm ok I will keep that in mind from now on, thanks